# The Area of an Irregular Hexagon

Tags: geometry, area

So I have a hexagon with $3$ side lengths of length $2$, and $3$ side lengths of length $1$. All side length of length $1$ are next to each other, and all sides of length $2$ are as well. The two angles between the sides of length $2$ are the same, as are the two angles shared by sides of length $1$. The two angles shared by sides $1$ and $2$ at opposite ends of the hexagon are the same as well. I would like to find out how to calculate out the area. I've tried splitting it into triangles, but that hasn't worked, and of course it's not regular, so I can't use the normal formula for a hexagon. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am hoping there is a version of Heron's formula for these kind of things....

Comment: You can split the hexagon into 2 quadrilaterals and use Bretschneider's formula [(_here_)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula) on each of them to calculate each quadrilateral area, the sum of which gives the area of the hexagon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I mis-read the lengths. The same analysis should still work.

I don't think that your question has a well defined answer.

Suppose that the lengths are arranged 2,1,2,1,2,1 around the hexagon. One can inscribe such a hexagon in an equilateral triangle of side length four and then remove the corners of the equilateral triangle to get that:
$$ A = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \left(4^2 - 3 \cdot 1^2 \right) \approx 5.62 $$

One can also arrange the lengths 1,1,1,2,2,2 around the hexagon. You can arrange so that there is a square of side length one with a trapezoid of sidelengths 2,2,2,1 and altitude $\sqrt{3}/2$ on top of it. This figure has area:
$$ A = 1^2 + 2 \left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \right) + 1 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \approx 2.29 $$

Comment: How exactly can you arrange it so that it's a $3x3$ square? wouldn't the angles be off?

Comment: The angles will be fine. Just try drawing the square and trapezoid.

Comment: @pgadey There may be one such case, but this is not unique I think.    IMO, the area is not a constant here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the sides of length $2$ and $1$ alternate as you go round the hexagon, and that all the angles are the same.  If you don't have some information like this I don't think it is possible to answer the problem.

In this case, by drawing two lines parallel to each side you can split the hexagon into $13$ identical equilateral triangles, and then it is easy to find the area.

Sorry I'm no good at diagrams, but I'm sure you can draw it for yourself.

Comment: @ David, I'm sorry that I didn't specify earlier, but these are not the dimensions of the hexagon. In listing the side lengths from left to right on the figure, this list would go like $1,1,1,2,2,2$, meaning all sides of length $1$ are next to each other, and all sides of length $2$ are as well.

Comment: You still need some angles.  Can I assume the two angles between sides of length $2$ are the same?  And the two angles between sides of length $1$ are the same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Still need more information.  Draw a diagram and look at the two vertices between sides of length $1$ and $2$.  You can imagine "pulling these points apart" which will give a hexagon of a different area.